# CoreService: how to get a list of Protocol schema's

Tags: 2013, core-service

I'm trying to fetch the list of Protocol Schema's from the content manager, but no luck.
I've tried both the GetSystemWideListXml method as the GetListXml, but I'm not sure which type of filter to use.

This will get me no schema's at all:

```
RepositoryItemsFilterData filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Schema };
filter.SchemaPurposes = new SchemaPurpose[] { SchemaPurpose.Protocol };
XElement schemas = this.CoreService.GetListXml(this.txtPublication.Text, filter);
```

I was kinda expecting something like a 'ProtocolSchemasFilterData' to use together with GetSystemWideListXml, but I can't find anything like this.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to search in system repository:

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Schema };
filter.SchemaPurposes = new[] { SchemaPurpose.Protocol };
IEnumerable<IdentifiableObjectData> list = client.GetList("tcm:0-0-7", filter);
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear to everyone: "tcm:0-0-7" is a special URI that corresponds to the aforementioned system repository.

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm! I would've never come up with this...

Comment: Noone would, that's why I pushed to put it into the API documentation a while ago

Comment: Note in 2013 release and onward, enabling the Core Service WCF trace (in TcmServiceHost.exe.config) is an effective way to find out which Core Service Requests the GUI uses to obtain its data. It will show you public secrets like this one. :-)